# Having trouble using a boolean method in an if statement

Tags: java

I want to use the method isLong() from Book class and use it in displayLongBooks() which is in the BookCollection method. Class BookCollection has bookList variable.  Variable bookList  is of ArrayList type and contains the collection of all books. All objects in the ArrayList are of  Book type.

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
    public class BookCollection
    {
   ArrayList<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<Book>();

   public BookCollection(){
   bookList.add(new Book(1001-01-141514, "Letones", "CS", 611));
   bookList.add(new Book(1002-01-141424, "Lewis", "CS", 477));
   bookList.add(new Book(1003-01-141434, "Smith", "MATH", 698));
   bookList.add(new Book(1004-01-141444, "Smith", "CS", 617));
   bookList.add(new Book(1005-01-141454, "Brown", "CHEM", 326));
   bookList.add(new Book(1006-01-141464, "Smith", "BIO", 127));
   bookList.add(new Book(1007-01-141474, "Sanket", "CS", 998));
 }
 public String toString()
 {

 }
 public void displayLongBooks()
 {
     System.out.println();
     System.out.println("LONG BOOKS");
     if (isLong() == true)
     System.out.println(bookList);
 }
 public void displayBooksFromAuthor(String author)
 {

 }
 public void displayBooksFromArea(String area)
 {

 }
 public void displayAverageLength()
 {

 }
}




import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Book
{
    String author;
    String area;
    int isbn;
    int pages;

 public Book (int isbn, String author, String area, int pages)
   {
      this.isbn = isbn;
      this.author = author;
      this.area = area;
      this.pages = pages;     
   }
 public boolean isLong()
   {
     if(pages>600)
     return true;
     else
     return false;
   }
 public String toString()
 {
     return "ISBN: " + this.isbn + "Author: " + this.author
            + "Subject: " + this.area + "Pages: " + this.pages;
 } 
 /**PrintWriter outfile = new PrintWriter (new FileWriter("books.txt"));
 outfile.write("100101141514, Letones, CS, 611");
 outfile.write(100201141424, Lewis, CS, 477);
 outfile.write(100301141434, Smith, MATH, 698);
 outfile.write(100401141444, Smith, CS, 617);
 outfile.write(100501141454, Brown, CHEM, 326);
 outfile.write(100601141464, Smith, BIO, 127);
 outfile.write(100701141474, Sanket, CS, 998);
 outfile.close();**/
}
```

Comment: `if (isLong() == true)` - No. Just `if (isLong())`. And while we're at it, the indentation is wrong at `System.out.println(bookList);`.

Comment: Likewise, `isLong()` should simply `return pages > 600;` which is already boolean (either true or false).

Comment: If `isLong()` is a method defined on `Book`, you need to call it on an instance of `Book`, e.g. `book.isLong()`.

Comment: Also, `1001-01-141514` is `-140514`. Probably not what you intended.

Comment: I did that but, I get an error saying that the compiler can't find method isLong

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic knowledge of object oriented programming. Explaining how objects and methods work is too broad and can be found in plenty of (official) tutorials online.

Comment: @khelwood gave the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to iterate the `bookList` for `Book`(s) and call `Book.isLong()` for each one. Using a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) that might look something like

```
public void displayLongBooks()
{
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("LONG BOOKS");
  for (Book b : bookList) { // <-- for each Book b in bookList
    if (b.isLong()) { // no need for == true
      System.out.println(b); // <-- b, not bookList
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you Elliott. I have another question. Do you know how I can input books into a file? At the bottom of the code I have variable outfile which should write each book into file books.txt, but I get error <identifier> expected.

Comment: @Matt It's not in a method.

Comment: I don't completely know what you mean by that.

Comment: @Matt I mean it's raw code outside of any method body. When would you expect it to run, and why?